# Options for storing metadata about CUPS print jobs?

Tags: python, concurrency, cups, ipp-protocol

I'm writing a print system that puts a simplified interface on top of CUPS. Users drop jobs into one queue, the system processes them in various ways (statistics, page quotas, etc.), and then offers the user a web interface to dispatch the job to one of multiple printers.

Since there may be several user kiosks, an admin station, etc., I need to store job metadata in something that can handle concurrent access. (Can you call data structures "re-entrant"?) A few options I can imagine are

- a MySQL database: massively overkill, but certainly stable and supported
- metadata files, with concurrent access handled manually: perfectly tailored to my needs, but then I have to re-implement a subset of MySQL's atomicity, and probably do it poorly
- write into the CUPS control files, using the provided thread-safe cupsipp.h API

The last option sounds most attractive, but there's a catch: I'm writing this in Python, and neither pycups nor pkipplib seem to have any way to modify a control file.

Edit: I should clarify that pkipplib can generate new IPP requests, but doesn't give any way to modify the existing control file. That is, I would have to make my updates by submitting them as new jobs.

Anyone have a better idea? Advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/)? Both of those are low overhead and easy to spin up, especially when you're not really dealing with complex datasets.